# Set dynamic height of webview depending on the content on an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

I want set dynamic height for webview depending on the dynamic text. I've tried

```
       [my_webview sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
```

But it didn't work for me. I want to set webview height dynamically.

Comment: [view sizeThatFits:] doesn't change view size. Try [view sizeToFit] but i'm not sure even this will work for a web view as it resizes depending on subviews, and web view doesn't have any typical subviews. Hence this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936041/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-uiwebview/3937599#3937599) to a similar question. The trick is to set the frame of the webView to a minimal height prior to sending `-sizeThatFits:`.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your web view as follows:

```
- (void)webViewSettings {
    NSString *htmlString = @"Your HTML String";
    NSString* descHtmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=300, user-scalable=yes\" /><div style='width:300px' id='ContentDiv'><font face=\"Arial\" size=2.5 color='#702f70'>%@</font></div></html>", htmlString];
    descHtmlString = [descHtmlString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:descHtmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}
```

Then implemented `UIWebViewDelegate` in your interface file and the following method in the implementation file:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        NSString *contentHeight = [self.descriptionWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('ContentDiv').offsetHeight"];
        self.descriptionWeb.frame = CGRectMake(10,webView.frame.origin.y, 300, [contentHeight floatValue]);
}
```